# How can I make my local actor more testable?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, refactoring, akka

I have an actor system which roughly looks like this:

```
class LocalActor extends Actor {

  // create the remote actor
  val remoteActor = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/RemoteActor")

  def receive = {
    case foo: String => remoteActor ! s"foo = ${foo}"
    case bar: Int => remoteActor ! s"bar = ${bar}"
    case _ => remoteActor ! "No clue..."
  }
}
```

I'd like to refactor it so `remoteActor`'s TCP/IP isn't hardcoded. The easiest change is to pass it explicitly to the constructor:

```
class LocalActor(TcpIp: String) extends Actor {

    val remoteActor = context.actorSelection(TcpIp)
    // ...
}
```

But I fear this might cause problems in the case that the TCP/IP address is already in use. The option that makes the most sense to me is to pass the actor (or a reference or similar) to the constructor -- is there an idiomatic way to do this in Akka?

I'm a bit confused because the type of `remoteActor` is `akka.actor.ActorSelection`, where I might have expected it to be an `Actor` or `ActorRef`.

Luckily the remote actor interacts only with `sender`, so it is fine the way it is; but the local actor is still tricky.

If my idea above is not a good one, what's the traditional way to make this more generic and testable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is directly passing the reference to your actor class:

```
object LocalActor {
  def prop(remoteActor: ActorRef) = Props(new LocalActor(remoteActor))
}

class LocalActor(remoteActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case foo: String => remoteActor ! s"foo = ${foo}"
    case bar: Int => remoteActor ! s"bar = ${bar}"
    case _ => remoteActor ! "No clue..."
  }
}
```

Then wherever you are creating your `LocalActor` you can also create the reference to `remoteActor` by resolving the `actorSelection`:

```
val system = ActorSystem("yourSystem")
implicit val resolveTimeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
val remoteActor = Await.result(system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://RemoteSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/RemoteActor").resolveOne(), resolveTimeout.duration)
val localActor = system.actorOf(LocalActor.props(remoteActor), "LocalActor")
```

Then for testing you just need to inject a `TestProbe`:

```
val testProbe = TestProbe()
val testingLocalActor = system.actorOf(LocalActor.props(testProbe.ref))
val testString = "TEST"
testingLocalActor ! testString
testProbe.expectMsg(s"foo = $testString")
```

Comment: `TestProbe` is brilliant! Cheers.